Term Reference field migration issue via CSV
I am trying to migrate term reference field ,rest all fields are migrated except term reference what i am doing wrong here .
uuid: 1bcec3e7-0a49-4473-87a2-6dca09b91aba
id: custom_taxonomy
label: 'Migrate Products from CSV'
migration_tags:
  - Aten Migrate CSV
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'modules/custom/custom_taxonomy/sources/migrate_plus.migration.custom_taxonomy.csv'
  ids:
    - ID
  fields:
    0:
      name: ID
      label: 'Unique Product ID'
    1:
      name: title
      label: 'Product Title'
    2:
      name: field_description
      label: 'Description'
    3:
      name: field_color
      label: 'Color'
    4:
      name: field_weight
      label: 'Weight'
    5:
      name: field_projects_data
      label: 'tags'  # Field for term reference
    
process:
  title: title
  field_description: field_description
  field_color: field_color
  field_weight: field_weight
  field_projects_data:
    plugin: entity_lookup
    source: field_projects_data
    value_key: name
    bundle_key: vid
    bundle: projects
    entity_type: taxonomy_term
    ignore_case: true # Optional, to allow case-insensitive matching
  type:  
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: newscontent
destination:
  plugin: entity:node

My Csv data is as follows


What exactly are you seeing happen? Does the "dominos" term exist in your "projects" vocabulary?

yes it exists .

What happens if you use entity_generate instead of entity_lookup?

What are the errors you are getting when you run drush migrate with --verbose option? Is there anything worth noticing?

no errors getting

It should (as sonfd mentions) be possible to achieve this with the entity_generate process plugin. This could look as follows:
  field_projects_data:
    - plugin: entity_generate
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
      bundle: projects
      source: field_projects_data

